# JQuery javascript argument undefined in IE and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following script and it works fine with FF and Safari.

```
function swapimage(cid) {
    jQuery('.imageshadowlg').attr("src", jQuery(cid).attr("src").replace('/thumb/', '/final/'));
                    }

<a href='javascript:;' id='expic1link' onclick='swapimage(expic1)' ><img id='expic1' src='../gallery/pics/thumb/test.jpg' /></a>
```

In IE, I'm getting following error

```
SCRIPT5009: 'expic1' is undefined
```

Chrome is giving following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined
swapimagegal.js:139
(anonymous function)s_gallery.aspx:1
onclick
```

These scripts are located in separate js file.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe try `onclick='swapimage("#expic1")'` but that is just a guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you pass any string as an argument it should be enclosed in quotes also the selector in the function is wrong. Try this

```
function swapimage(cid) {
    jQuery('.imageshadowlg').attr("src", jQuery('#'+ cid).attr("src").replace('/thumb/', '/final/'));
                    }

<a href='javascript:;' id='expic1link' onclick='swapimage("expic1")' ><img id='expic1' src='../gallery/pics/thumb/test).jpg' /></a>
```

Comment: That's totally make sense. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Whatever selector you are passing in is not working. My guess would be that you forgot to put a `#` or `.` in front of the name.